# saving ip config persistent with nmcli or something equal?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, linux-networking

I am using RocksLinux where I set up my IP addresses by hand with the standard command "IP" and "IP -6" for my IP version 4 and 6 addresses.

Now I want to save with NetworkManager, or something equal to the configuration persistently, that if I reboot the machine, I don't have to add these addresses manually once again.

Any ideas?

best, Tamer

Comment: As you suggested in your question, `NetworkManager` should work to set up persistent configurations. Are you having any specific problems with this tool?

Comment: Meanwhile solved, I thought I could readout with "nmcli" and exising configuration that was setup with the "ip" and "ip -6" commands.    
So I cleaned up everything and did the config entirely with nmcli. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem had been solved by deleting all previous configurations.

1. I activated NetworkManager with systemctl enable NetworkManager
2. I removed with nmcli all conections and I deleted from /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ everything there was something inside
3. I rebooted the machine, through the KVM console I logged in (i
   switched on passwordf auth via ssh, which I later deacivated and
   activated publi key auth after completing the config).
4. I added only one connection where all IPv4 addresses with the gateway Gateway and all IPv6 addresses with the one gateway is mentioned.
5. NetworkManager (nmcli) wrote a new config file. I rebooted and everything was setup permanently within the boot process.

The only thing I have to figure out is that all services start AFTER the ip addresses and routing are set....